# Do all the built-in functions in python take one or multiple parameters or there are exceptions to some functions?

Tags: python, function, built-in

Do all the built-in functions in python take one or multiple parameters or there are exceptions to some functions? An example would be-

```py
num = [1, 2, 3, 4]

num = sorted[num]

print(num)
```

Comment: `sorted[]`? Did you mean `sorted()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [Built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

`locals()` is a function that takes no arguments and seems to be the only one.

There are more functions like `dir()`, where the argument is optional, so you can use it without parameters. When used without a parameter, the only effect could be a side effect. In the example, something will be printed to the screen.

- `bool()` returns `False`.
- `bytearray()` returns a bytearray of length 0
- `bytes()` returns a bytes object of length 0
- `complex()` returns 0 + 0j
- `dir()` prints a list of local variables
- `float()` return 0.0
- `help()` prints some text
- ...